# Index of imagelist is -1 a value tha creates an exception

Tags: c#, indexing, imagelist

Hello I am making an imageviewer in c#.  The thing is that works correctly, I can see on click the next image.

But for `values = 5 and =-1` gives me an exception.

How to fix this my code is this?

I get this message

> InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.

Code:

```
int I;
if (pictureBox2.Visible == true)
{
     I = I - 1;
     pictureBox2.Image = imageList2.Images[I];
}
```

This image list has 4 pictures with + goes up to the fourth then with the code above goes down to the first one.

When I press the button one more time it gives me the error message that I am describing how can I fix this?

Comment: It is up to you how to fix it - exception is explicit enough to say that index is not valid, so it is up to you to keep index in valid range depending on design of your program. One solution is treat values outside the range as lowest/highest in valid range...

Answer (score 0):

This keep I in range:

```
I = I - 1;
I = I < 0 ? 0 : I >= imageList2.Images.Length ? imageList2.Images.Length - 1 : I;
```

Comment: Looks hard to grasp for an average coder: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Comment: Maybe, but it's the best i can do in this moment.

Comment: What about: `I = I - 1; if (I < 0) I = 0;` and for the next image button: `I = I + 1; if (I > imageList2.Images.Length-1) I = imageList2.Images.Length-1;`

Comment: Better for the `Length`, but prefer shorten version.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to follow Alessandro's example yet, you can always try the old-fashioned if/else if

```
if(I<0)
  I=4;
else if(I>4)
  I=0;
```

You just insert that code after the I value is changed.

Comment: You can achive this with:  I += 1; I %= imageCount; _see for % ->_ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx

Comment: Call me old-fashioned, I find the if/else much easier to read.